# Shopping at a church-associated thrift store

Tags: halacha, transactions, christianity, business, safek

If you know that let's say John Hancock's thrift store's profits go to a church are you allowed to purchase things there? What if you don't where the money goes but are in Safek whether it goes to a church?

CYLOR

Comment: This post is not really an _exact_ duplicate of ["May I shop at a church-owned thrift store?"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66401/may-i-shop-at-a-church-owned-thrift-store), since this post includes two different questions in it.