# Can you shop at a church-owned thrift store?

Tags: halacha, christianity, transactions, business, environment

Can you shop at a second-hand shop owned by a church, such as a Salvation Army thrift store?

Please cite sources.

Comment: Salvation Army uses large portions of their income to proselytise אחינו בית ישראל, so there are mon-halachic reasons to avoid them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked my questions to one of the rabbis who worked for a local synagogue.  He's a charedi Ashkenazi rabbi.

He said the following:

- I shouldn't shop at a church-owned thrift store — that it's supporting idol worship.  The only exception would be if it's one of the few denominations which treats Yoshke as a prophet, not as a god.
- Even if I would have to travel half an hour to get to a non-church-owned thrift store, it makes no difference.  I still can't do it.

Keep in mind that there are lots of other places to get cheap merchandise, though, including:

- Garage sales.
- Craigslist.
- Ebay.
- Refurbished-electronics stores.

Comment: I think that your question would be muich enhanced if you could eventually edit some reasoning as to why your Hareidi rav states this. Mind you, there are probably many opinions on this subject, but, I would have trouble having an educated debate without understanding his reasoning. Re Salvation Army, I'm uncertain if it is directly "Church owned" in the sense of fitting into a halachic problem. That's a separate question, as they are "3rd party".

Comment: @DanF: What was his reasoning? I suspect the following: According to many opinions, worshipping Jesus is idol worship. Shopping in a church-owned thrift shop might therefore be supporting idol worship.

Comment: @DanF: Also, the Salvation Army [is a church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvation_Army).

Comment: But someone on eBay could be supporting any number of pagan practises, how is that any better?

Comment: @curiousdannii: Good question. My hunch is this: We know that shopping at the Salvation Army is definitely supporting a church, and so we avoid it. We could also investigate the religious practices of an Ebay user before doing business with them, but the common custom seems to be that we don't. Why not? I guess because, although some Ebay users might be idol-worshippers, most aren't. Side note: Despite all this, it's still meritorious to do business with Jews who keep Shabbat when practicable.

Answer (score 5):

There is a health food store in Maryland owned by the 7th Day Adventists Church; many of their canned products are certified kosher by well-respected kashrut organizations.  Nevertheless, Rabbi Hillel Klavan, shlita, who is also the son of the great rabbi of the early 20th Century, Rabbi Joshua Klavan, zt'l, emphatically told my wife and I that we should not buy from that store because the profits go to the church.

Comment: The hechsher is on the food not the company

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Noah Whittenburg from Yeshiva University - [Shoel U’Mashiv](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/1027114) says you can shop and donate at the Salvation Army

[The OU says you can buy from the Salvation Army or a church.](https://outorah.org/p/51840/)

Comment: What about "Lo Techanem" (לא תחנם) when you donate to them?

Comment: @IsraelReader I may be mistaken, but isn't לא תחנם only relevant for Eretz Yisrael?

Comment: @Harel13 You are mistaken. https://olamot.net/shiurim/%d7%9c%d7%90-%d7%aa%d7%97%d7%a0%d7%9d/

Comment: I don't see it stated anywhere there that this is also regarding חוץ לארץ. I do know however that לא תחנם with regards to חניית קרקע is specifically for ארץ ישראל. https://olamot.net/shiurim/%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9D-%D7%91/